# Maven Build Profile Activation

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-profiles

I know there are some related topics but still I can't understand how to do it.

I'm learning maven and currently in process of creating build profiles. I want maven to auto detect the currently installed java version on my machine. Let's say I'm working in our office which uses **(jdk7)** or home `(jdk8)`, I want the `<source>` and `<target>` elements in `maven-compiler-plugin` pom.xml to auto detect the `java -version` regardless of environment (office / home). I've read about `activation` but can't perfectly understand the purpose.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>   
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>    
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Not questioning your intention here, but why would you work against java7? Last public update was in 2015, its time to move on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi I don't think you can have your build, environment aware automatically, just using the defaults, you need some help of profiles and their activation capability see [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). What you can do is introduce 2 different profiles, in each profile you can define the JDK you want, and it will be activated for your if present, then you can configure either the compiler plugin with different source /target or, just set different values for a a property that is going to indicate the java version. Example:

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
     <id>java8</id>
     <activation>
       <jdk>1.8</jdk>
     </activation>
   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>   
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>    
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   </profile>
<profile>
     <id>java7</id>
     <activation>
       <jdk>1.7</jdk>
     </activation>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>   
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>    
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 5):

For Java 9 the following profiles can be used.

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>java8</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>1.8</jdk>
            </activation>
            (...)
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>java9</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>9</jdk>
            </activation>
            (...)
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: Or for 8 and post-8: `<jdk>1.8</jdk>` and `<jdk>[9,)</jdk>`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to declare two mutually exclusive profiles, one for jdk7 builds and one for jdk8 builds. Each profile declaration has two important parts:

The `activation` element is like a conditional, and is nested within . Is your profile on or off? You will want to set up the `jdk` based activation. Example for your jdk7 profile:

```xml
<activation>
  <jdk>1.7</jdk>
</activation>
```

Next you'll want to define the property or properties that get set when your profile is active. Example for jdk7:

```xml
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.7<jdk.version>
</properties>
```

Both of those sections get combined with an `id` element (e.g. `<id>jdk7</id>`) and nested within a `profile` element.

If you have any problems getting the jdk detection activation to work, I'd suggest experimenting with an explicit trigger, such as invoking maven with `mvn -P jdk7`.

From the sounds of it, you want a jdk7 and a jdk8 profile to be defined within your `pom.xml`. But another option is to have a single profile which is always on, but define the `jdk.version` property for the profile differently inside of your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file. The settings.xml file at the office would have the jdk7 properties; at home it would have jdk8.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: I've tried to changed the activation jdk value to 1.4 just to test and why i still get the value of jdk.version which is 1.7 ?

Comment: If you set the activation value to 1.4, then the property won't get set unless your jdk version is 1.4. And if it does get set, it will just be set to the property value defined within the `<properties>` element. What was the actual jdk version used to run the test? What was the value of your `<properties>` element?